# jQuery Mobile User Login

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

When I try to login in with a username and password to another page, nothing happens just that the page refreshes.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="../Connections/VT.asp" -->
<%
' *** Validate request to log in to this site.
MM_LoginAction = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
If Request.QueryString <> "" Then MM_LoginAction = MM_LoginAction + "?" + Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString)
MM_valUsername = CStr(Request.Form("username"))
If MM_valUsername <> "" Then
  Dim MM_fldUserAuthorization
  Dim MM_redirectLoginSuccess
  Dim MM_redirectLoginFailed
  Dim MM_loginSQL
  Dim MM_rsUser
  Dim MM_rsUser_cmd

  MM_fldUserAuthorization = ""
  MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "#page2"
  MM_redirectLoginFailed = "error.html"

  MM_loginSQL = "SELECT Username, Password"
  If MM_fldUserAuthorization <> "" Then MM_loginSQL = MM_loginSQL & "," & MM_fldUserAuthorization
  MM_loginSQL = MM_loginSQL & " FROM dbo.Test_Register_Users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?"
  Set MM_rsUser_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
  MM_rsUser_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_VT_STRING
  MM_rsUser_cmd.CommandText = MM_loginSQL
  MM_rsUser_cmd.Parameters.Append MM_rsUser_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 200, 1, 70, MM_valUsername) ' adVarChar
  MM_rsUser_cmd.Parameters.Append MM_rsUser_cmd.CreateParameter("param2", 200, 1, 50, Request.Form("password")) ' adVarChar
  MM_rsUser_cmd.Prepared = true
  Set MM_rsUser = MM_rsUser_cmd.Execute

  If Not MM_rsUser.EOF Or Not MM_rsUser.BOF Then 
    ' username and password match - this is a valid user
    Session("MM_Username") = MM_valUsername
    If (MM_fldUserAuthorization <> "") Then
      Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = CStr(MM_rsUser.Fields.Item(MM_fldUserAuthorization).Value)
    Else
      Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = ""
    End If
    if CStr(Request.QueryString("accessdenied")) <> "" And true Then
      MM_redirectLoginSuccess = Request.QueryString("accessdenied")
    End If
    MM_rsUser.Close
    Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginSuccess)
  End If
  MM_rsUser.Close
  Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginFailed)
End If
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/vtapp.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<%=MM_LoginAction%>">
      <table width="284" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Enter Username and Password</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="blay" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input name="password" type="text" id="password" value="BBBBBB" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="  Sign In  " />
          </div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">Welcome User</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon checking everything that is written, all the codes are right are is supposed to work.

Comment: Is `"#page2"` supossed to be another page?

Comment: Yes #page2 is another page on that same page

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but response.redirect needs a page not only a hash. Shouldn't it be `MM_redirectLoginSuccess=MM_LoginAction+"#page2"`?

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver produces really hideous ASP code.  The best advice I can offer is for you to google for a tutorial on how to write login forms in Classic ASP.  There's one here

http://www.w3schools.com/website/web_asp_login.asp

And there are plenty of others.  Once you've done that then delete all the Dreanweaver generated rubbish and replace it with your own code.

Anyway, looking at the HTML in your page I can see no logic which determines whether to display the login form or the welcome message.  Try something along the lines of

```
<% if Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = "" then %>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<%=MM_LoginAction%>">
     (rest of your form here, I'm not going to copy it all)
  </form>
<% else %>
  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
   <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content">Welcome User</div>
  </div>
<% end if %>
```

Comment: what i want it to do is when it validates the username and password are right, it should then take you to the #page2 which will give u the welcome message

Comment: The comment MC ND makes above about Response.Redirect is probably valid, and it might be worth changing line 17 to MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "name-of-your-page.asp#page2". Looking at your code though it appears that you can scroll down to the welcome message whether you're logged in or not.  Surely you want it to be only available if the user is logged in